# ODBC connectivity in PHP

Tags: php

I have created an ODBC DSN (icamexamdata) for a MS Access DB. Mine is Win 7 OS. I used the following code to connect to the DSN

```
$conn=odbc_connect('icamexamdata','','');
```

I couldn't connect and I get the following error.

> Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

Can anybody help?

Comment: is your odbc properly config?

Comment: I am not sure. I could create a DSN. I tried in Java JDBC and I got SQL Exception [Microsoft][ODBC Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and the Application